# Consulta personalizada MySQL JSON

Tags: php

[image: Consulta de registros perrsonalizados]

Amigos tengo una duda, estoy manejando la version 5 de php pero me marca error en la linea 32, no se como llenar el arreglo para que me lo mande en JSON, creo que lo que esta dentro del while no funciona, "Si me hace la consulta, pero solo si pongo el select * from"

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para esta y futuras preguntas ten en cuenta que generalmente ayuda más que pongas el texto del código que una imagen. Las imágenes no se ven bien en dispositivos pequeños y, en este caso concreto la imagen se corta, impide ver la consulta SQL completa. Tu código da la impresión de un código antiguo, la extensión `mysql_*` que usas está obsoleta, la forma de llenar el array que usas es ya poco frecuente. De todos modos, conviene que digas cuál es el error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: si, se que esta obsoleta, sin embargo el servidor donde tengo alojados los datos, maneja esta version, mas delante manejare otro servidor mas nuevo. el error es de que me dice que $response en la linea 38 que no tiene datos, solo quiero hacer esa consulta con ese SQL que tengo en la linea 18 y sacarlo en JSON

Comment: Como te decía, no siquiera se puede revisar la consulta de la línea 18 completa porque se trunca en la imagen. [Edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/173776/edit) cambiando la imagen por el texto del código. De todos modos, revisa que en esa consulta tienes bien escritos los nombres de tablas/columnas, también puedes probar a ejecutarla en el manejador de BD directamente para verificar si funciona. Y aunque tengas PHP 5 ya puedes pasar a PDO o a MySQLi, no tienes que esperar a la versión 7 para usar un código que sea más seguro y más óptimo.

Comment: Podría ser que no estás asignando un alias a la tabla negociosVinculados ni a usuariosempleados. Un ejemplo sería "SELECT n.Nombre, n.Logotipo FROM negociosVinculados n". Para una respuesta más concreta sería necesario ver el resto de tu consulta, ya que no se ve la última parte.